# unable to update a state, it's a paradox case

Tags: reactjs, loops, jsx

So, I seriously don't understand what's wrong. everything should work, but it's not.

We have a list of objects named clients that looks like this.

```
[
    {
        "Name": "SOME NAME",
        "Synonyms": [
            "ABCABC", "ABDABC", "ABSABC"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "SOME OTHER NAME",
        "Synonyms": [
            "MEDMED", "MXEMXE", "MLSMLS"
        ]
    },
....
]
```

```
      for (const client of clients) {
        if ( client.Name.includes(value) || client.Synonyms.includes(value) )
        {
          console.log(client.Name)
          this.setState((prevState) => ({
            ClientNameList: Array.from(
              new Set([...prevState.ClientNameList, client.Name])
            ),
          }));
        }
      }
```

If I enter "SOME NAME", my state get updated with ["SOME NAME"] as expected, however if I enter "ABCABC" the if statement returns true as expected and execute the block of code that contains the call to update the state, it prints the correct client.Name which is SOME NAME, but my state never change and stays []

I spend few hours and could not figure it out

UPDATE:

so I figured out the problem is coming from  that does not display those values

I am still having an issue fixing it

```
                     <AutoComplete
                        dataSource={this.state.ClientNameList}
                        value={this.state.ClientName}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        onSelect={this.handleSelection}
                        placeholder=""
                      />
```

Comment: what i meant to say, is that the if statement return true and execute the block and print the correct client.name, however the state don't change. since that block of code is executed I don't understand why the state is not changing.

Comment: Could you provide the code of your state (reducer) and component? Otherwise it's a little bit tricky to understand what could went wrong with the state.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue https://jsfiddle.net/v2osjgyL/1/